# Laravel 5.3 Missing IronMQ Support

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.3.17 and have found that it doesn't comes with a IronMQ driver. I've tried installing the driver from https://github.com/LaravelCollective/iron-queue but composer fails to install it due to unresolved requirements. Here's the composer's output:

```
Using version ^5.2 for laravelcollective/iron-queue
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravelcollective/iron-queue v5.2.2 requires iron-io/iron_mq ~2.0 -> satisfiable by iron-io/iron_mq[2.0.0, 2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or m
inimum-stability
- laravelcollective/iron-queue v5.2.1 requires iron-io/iron_mq ~2.0 -> satisfiable by iron-io/iron_mq[2.0.0, 2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or m
inimum-stability
- laravelcollective/iron-queue v5.2 requires iron-io/iron_mq ~2.0 -> satisfiable by iron-io/iron_mq[2.0.0, 2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or min
imum-stability
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.3.17
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- laravelcollective/iron-queue v5.2.3 requires illuminate/queue 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/queue[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.2
7, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
- laravelcollective/iron-queue v5.2.4 requires illuminate/queue 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/queue[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.2
7, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
- Installation request for laravel/framework == 5.3.17.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.17].
- Installation request for laravelcollective/iron-queue ^5.2 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/iron-queue[v5.2, v5.2.1, v5.2.2, v5.2.3, v5.2.4].
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be late, but for anyone with the same issue, try using the following in your composer.yml:

```
"laravelcollective/iron-queue": "5.3.*"
```